# Best way to change a import path using Python AST

Tags: python, python-import, abstract-syntax-tree

I have some code like the following and I would like to use Python AST to change the import path from foo.bar to xxx.yyy. It's pretty easy to find the import statement (`import foo.bar` here) and rename it with AST, but what's the recommended way to find the places it uses the imports (`foo.bar.run()` here) and rename those as well? So far the only solution I can think of is to use visit_Attribute to find all first-level attributes (`run` here) and try to modify it. But I'm wondering if there's a better solution (e.g. existing helper library) Thanks!

```
import foo.bar
foo.bar.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Bowler](https://github.com/facebookincubator/bowler) (or some similar library) is probably better than using AST directly